# How can I create nested option groups in React Select (V2)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

In React-Select V2, we're able to create option groups by passing an `options` param like so:

```
options = [
    { label: 'Group', options: [
        { label: 'Option 1', value: '1' },
        { label: 'Option 2', value: '2' }
    ]}
]
```

I need to be able to go another layer deep, something like:

```
options = [
    { label: 'Group', options: [
        { label: 'Option 1', value: '1' },
        { label: 'Option 2', options: [
            { label: 'Option 2-a', value: '2a' },
            { label: 'Option 2-b', value: '2b' },
        ]}
    ]}
]
```

Which would display the options "Option 2-a" and "Option 2-b" in a group under "Option 2". The approach above doesn't work out of the box, so I want to know if there's a way to create nested groups in React-Select V2.

Comment: This is an interesting use case that I don't think React-Select currently supports. Would be a great feature request though.

Comment: agreed with @Steve-Cutter-Blades you should do a feature request. As in V2, groups have been implemented, it could be a finish

Comment: This issue has been a requested feature for react-select and has now been implemented in [this](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/pull/3873) PR. You can find a working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-8xxyx?file=/index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who comes here with a similar need, I implemented this recursive work-around.

```
const renderNestedOption = (props, label, nestedOptions) => {
  const {
    cx,
    getStyles,
    innerProps,
    selectOption,   
  } = props;

  // Will be applied to nested optgroup headers 
  const nestedLabelClassName = cx(
    css(getStyles('groupHeading', props)),
    { option: true },
    'nested-optgroup-label',
  );    

  return (
    <div className="nested-optgroup">
      <div className={nestedLabelClassName}>
        {label}
      </div>
      {nestedOptions.map((nestedOption) => {
        if (nestedOption.options) {
          // Read below
          // Read above
          return renderNestedOption(props, nestedOption.label, nestedOption.options);
        }

        const nestedInnerProps = innerProps;
        nestedInnerProps.onClick = () => selectOption(nestedOption);
        return (
          <div className="nested-optgroup-option" key={nestedOption.value}>
            <components.Option {...props} innerProps={nestedInnerProps}>
              {nestedOption.label}
            </components.Option>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>   
  ); 
};

const Option = (props) => {
  const {
    children,
    data,
  } = props;
  const nestedOptions = data.options;

  if (nestedOptions) {
    const label = data.label;
    return renderNestedOption(props, label, nestedOptions);
  }

  return (
    <components.Option {...props}>
      {children}
    </components.Option>
  );
};
```

Then in your select component, replace the `Option` component with the custom `Option` component we just created.

#### EDIT

There's an open pull request to support this functionality:
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/pull/2750