# Multi select with child options

Tags: reactjs, select, react-select, react-multiselect-checkboxes

im new to react. I want to have multi select with child options.(eg. year - parent , months - child)
when year is selected all months in that year should be able to be selected
something similar to this. months shuld also be able to select/deselct and can be opened/ closed in year option.

[image: example dropdown]

can anyone suggest if any library is available for this purpose?

Comment: check this out https://react-select.com/home this might serve the purpuse

Comment: basically i need a drop down within a drop down. Im check if any readymade library is available. I hope react-select doesn't serve this purpose.

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63920749/nested-dropdown-in-react-select

Comment: @monesulhaque thanks. but i think group heading is not selectable. Still thanks for the suggestion.